# VB.net Serial.write slow on Windows 7

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, serial-port

I have the following problem on a Windows 7 using VB.net with .NET Framework 4.0.
I have to send via a serial port a buffer of byte. The PC act like master and a device connected as slave receive the buffer. Each byte must be spaced from its next by a certain amount of time expressed in microseconds.

This is my code snippet

```
                        Dim t1 As New Stopwatch
                        Dim WatchTotal As New Stopwatch

                        WatchTotal.Reset()
                        WatchTotal.Start()

                        t1.Stop()
                        For i As Integer = 0 To _buffer.Length - 1

                            SerialPort1.Write(_buffer, i, 1)

                            t1.Reset()
                            t1.Start()

                            While ((1000000000 * t1.ElapsedTicks / Stopwatch.Frequency) < 50000) ' wait 50us
                            End While
                            t1.Stop()
                        Next

                        WatchTotal.Stop()

                        Debug.Print(WatchTotal.ElapsedMilliseconds)
```

Everything loop inside a thread.

Everything works correctly but on a machine with Windows 7 the Serial.write of 1 byte takes 1ms so if we have to send 1024 bytes it takes 1024ms.

This is confirmed by printing the elapsed time

```
Debug.Print(WatchTotal.ElapsedMilliseconds)
```

The problem seems to be in SerialPort.Write method.
The same code on a machine with Windows 10 takes less than 1ms.

The problem is more visible when we have to send many buffers of byte, in this case we send 16 buffers of 1027 bytes. On Win 7 it takes less than 20 seconds, in Win10 it takes the half or less (to send 1 buffers of 1027 bytes it takes approximately 120-150ms and less than 5 seconds to send 16 buffers of data).

Does anyone have any idea what that might depend on?

Thanks

---

### EDIT 22/05/2020

If i remove the debug printing and the little delay to pause the communication i always have about 1027ms for sending 1027 bytes so i think that the problem belong only to SerialPort method and not to the timing or stopwatch object. This happen on a Windows 7 machine. The same executable on a Windows 10 machine go fast as expected.

```
                        For i As Integer = 0 To _buffer.Length - 1
                            SerialPort1.Write(_buffer, i, 1)
                        Next
```

Comment: Could you use one of the standard Baud rates instead?

Comment: What version of .Net?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.0 and baudrate is 115200 bps. I can't go faster.

Comment: Could be occurring asynchronously.  You want a fixed time for each char in TOTAL. You starting the timer AFTER the write. You want to start the timer first, then send, and then wait what is left over. Thus you ALWAYS spend same amount of time to send out the 1 char regardless if hardware is a bit slower/faster to accept the 1 char. Seems to me that some other bit/status should be read to tell that the character has been processed so you can move on as fast as hardware will allow. But if you fixing time, then make it same for full operation - not after char gone out.

Answer (score 0):

One thing, your wait code seems cumbersome, try this.

```
        'one tick is 100ns, 10 ticks is as microsecond
        Const wait As Long = 50L * 10L ' wait 50us as ticks
        While t1.ElapsedTicks < wait
        End While
```

Busy loops are problematic and vary from machines.  As I recall serial port handling was not very good on Win7, but I could be mistaken.

It is hard to believe that the receiver is that time sensitive.

Comment: The slave is a microcontroller that receive every byte and store it in the flash and yes, it is really sensistive. I've tryed your code and produce the same output of my previous version:

1027
1027
1027
1030
1027
1027      The problem seems to be in Serial.write method because if i remove the while statement i get the same output on the console

Comment: I think is a SerialPort problem, see my edit in original post

Answer (score 0):

If the Win7 workstation doesn't have or isn't using a high resolution timer, then that could account for the described difference.

From the Remarks section of the [StopWatch class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch):

> The Stopwatch measures elapsed time by counting timer ticks in the underlying timer mechanism. If the installed hardware and operating system support a high-resolution performance counter, then the Stopwatch class uses that counter to measure elapsed time. Otherwise, the Stopwatch class uses the system timer to measure elapsed time. Use the Frequency and IsHighResolution fields to determine the precision and resolution of the Stopwatch timing implementation.

Check the [IsHighResolution field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution) to determine if this is what is occurring.

Comment: I don't think is a question of timer resolution. See the edit in the original post.